# show top 10 by PowerPivot

Tags: filter, powerpivot

I have a dataset with 4 columns, namely:

```
Sales, Year, Type, ID
```

**Question:**

How can I show the TOP 10 based on sales, showing other 3 columns using PowerPivot?

For example like this:

```
ID   Year Type Sales
X    X    X    X
```

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far, and what specific problem are you having? Read [ask] then [edit] your question.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need power pivot for that purpose. A simple table will do the job. Format/Insert your dataset as a table and  Do as follows  (Office 365):

1. Click on Sales (the 'Down Button')
2. Select Number Filters
3. Select Top 10.
4. In the dialogue box select "Top", "10", "Items"

If it has to be power pivot/pivot table, I think you will have to merge the three columns 'ID', 'Year', 'Type'

Screenshot attached:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wdm5P.png)